# Out of memory error in center crop of bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, android-imageview, android-bitmap

I am trying to center crop my bitmap image but it is throwing OOM error after sometime in my following function and as a result the application is crashing. What I can change in my following function to handle the center crop?

```
private Bitmap cropBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap bmp;
    if (bitmap.getWidth() >= bitmap.getHeight()) {
        bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                bitmap,
                bitmap.getWidth() / 2 - bitmap.getHeight() / 2,
                0,
                bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap.getHeight());
    } else {
        bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                bitmap,
                0,
                bitmap.getHeight() / 2 - bitmap.getWidth() / 2,
                bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getWidth());
    }
    return bmp;
}
```

And here is my error log

08-18 20:14:15.270 2974-2974/entertainment.minersinc.tfhy.dev D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
08-18 20:14:15.272 2974-2974/entertainment.minersinc.tfhy.dev E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: entertainment.minersinc.tfhy.dev, PID: 2974
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 12124336 byte allocation with 2126672 free bytes and 2MB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:905)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:882)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:802)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:727)
        at entertainment.minersinc.tfhy.customviews.CircularImageView.cropBitmap(CircularImageView.java:206)
        at entertainment.minersinc.tfhy.customviews.CircularImageView.updateShader(CircularImageView.java:188)
        at entertainment.minersinc.tfhy.customviews.CircularImageView.loadBitmap(CircularImageView.java:159)
        at entertainment.minersinc.tfhy.customviews.CircularImageView.onDraw(CircularImageView.java:128)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17201)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16183)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16967)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3731)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3517)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16178)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16967)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3731)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3517)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17204)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16183)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16967)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3731)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.drawChild(RecyclerView.java:4774)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3517)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17204)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.draw(RecyclerView.java:4173)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16183)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16967)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3731)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3517)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17204)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16183)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16967)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3731)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3517)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17204)
        at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.draw(NestedScrollView.java:1888)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16183)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16967)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3731)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3517)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17204)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16183)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16967)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3731)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3517)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16178)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16967)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3731)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.drawChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1246)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3517)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17204)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16183)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16967)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3731)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3517)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16178)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16967)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3731)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3517)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16178)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16967)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3731)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3517)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16178)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16967)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3731)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3517)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16178)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16967)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3731)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3517)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16178)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16967)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3731)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3517)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17204)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:753)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16183)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:648)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:654)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:762)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2818)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2626)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2233)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1272)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6408)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)

Comment: try `BitmapRegionDecoder`

Comment: Work with smaller images. 12124336 bytes for a `Bitmap` is equivalent to a 1741x1741 pixel image. This is much too large -- you will be lucky if you can get that to work once for the lifetime of your app. You are also down to only 2MB of free heap space overall, so determine where your memory is going and try to use less memory elsewhere.

Comment: The wrong thing is that you start with a bitmap. Where does this bitmap come from?

Answer (score 0):

Your bitmap is too large. This is obvious. 
Try this `android:largeHeap="true"` in your manifest under `application` tag.  
Maybe it will work.